# Angular 4 - On router.Navigate to new component,the previous component's api code block is executed in background

Tags: angular

On router.navigation to ErrorComponent from XYZComponent, the 
refreshData() (api call) method of XYZComponent is called in background in ErrorCOmponentPage.

SO why the api code block of XYZComponent called when navigated to ErrorComponent and how to avoid it.

```
export class XYZComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  timerSubscription: any;
  timervalue: any = null;
  private subscription;
  interval: any;

 ngOnInit() {
   this.timervalue = '10000'//refresh interval

   this.refreshData();
   this.interval = setInterval(() => { 
     this.refreshData(); 
   }, this.timervalue);//this code calls every 10000 ms
}
```

**api call**

```
  private refreshData(): void {
    this.subscription = this.xyzService.getData().subscribe(data => { 
     this.teamView = data; this.setTitleAsSupervisorName(); 
     this.ValidateUser(data) });
  }

 ValidateUser(responseData) {
   if (responseData == null) {
     this.router.navigate(['/errors', {
       errormsg: 'User Not recoginesed as a Super User, please try later.',
       errorcode: '404'
     }]);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called every 10 seconds because you told it to run every 10 seconds, and never told it to stop.

Use `ngOnDestroy()` on your `XYZComponent` to clear the interval when the component is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You set an interval, did you think about deleting it ?

```
ngOnDestroy() { clearInterval(this.interval); }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set an interval it is window scoped, so it create a closure and the running code is not dependant of you component. So it is still running since you never cleared your interval on XYZComponent "destruction".

[Here the doc of setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

You should use the [OnDestroy hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) to clear the interval when the component is dismissed.

```
    export class XYZComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
          timerSubscription: any;
          timervalue: any = null;
          private subscription;
          interval: any;

          ngOnDestroy () {
              clearInterval(this.interval);
          }

          ngOnInit() {
              this.timervalue = '10000'//refresh interval

              this.refreshData();
              this.interval = setInterval(() => { 
                this.refreshData(); 
              }, this.timervalue);//this code calls every 10000 ms
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer......ngOnDestroy is not being called when navigated to ErrorComponent from XYZComponent, can i use  clearInterval(this.interval) in ValidateUser(responseData) method before navigating...is it right

Comment: it's very surprising that the destroy hook is not called. Do you have any error in the console ?